# About differing coding styles/guidelines

Tags: c#, coding-style

Something came into my head last night. I was wondering why we still have different coding styles between projects. Since style is something personal, I think it's better to treat it as such. Why don't we? Are there any technical limitations to this?

Let me give you some examples:

```C#
// Code sample 1
randomObject
    .Colors
    .Where(item => item.Color == Color.Red)
    .Count();

// Code sample 2    
randomObject.Colors.Where(item => item.Color == Color.Red).Count();

// Code sample 3
randomObject.Colors.Count(item => item.Color == Color.Red);

// Code sample 4
if(criteria) {
    // Do stuff
} else {
}

// Code sample 5
if( criteria )
{
    // Do stuff
}
else {}
```

Code sample 1 and 2 technically do the same (if I'm not mistaken). On the other hand, code sample 2 and 3 are different, they do something different under the hood, but give the same result. Therefor it cannot be rewritten to code example 1, yet there's a possibility to format it as such. Code sample 4 and 5, I think you've seen them before, I don't think they need further explaination.

So, what made me wonder... Can't we work locally with the coding style of preference, and before committing/checking in, code will be reformatted according to server settings.

** Side information: I code at different repositories, all differing in code styles. Switching between these always means I have to change my mindset in order to match their style.

** Thinking out loud: Can't we commit/check in [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)s?

Comment: You can try using auto formatting option available in IDE's. Like in eclipse you can use ctrl + shift + f to format your code. You can also define your custom formatting preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using tools like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/%20ReSharper) for VS (not free unfortunately), which provide customizable code formatting hints. You could have a different setting for each repository.

My opinion is to stick to the "official" repository style, if any, although it can be annoying. It improves the readability of the code for all developers. If there is no such standard, then try pick a style which won't be an obstacle to your colleagues.

For instance sample 5 is much preferable over 4, because it's less crowded and it's easier to see what line is doing what, in my opinion at least. I also think sample 1 is better than 2, although I'd have used another variant:

```
randomObject.Colors
            .Where(item => item.Color == Color.Red)
            .Count();
```

Also, sample 2 and 3 give the same result, but 3 is more efficient, besides being more concise. I think it's highly preferable.

About your idea to code locally with one's own style and reformat before committing, how would you do that? There are tools for that but I believe they cannot be trusted blindly, so you would need to check that everything works as intended after reformatting. This takes time, probably more that it would take to code with the "standard" style from the beginning. You could reformat by hand, but it probably worse.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it. I agree on that there are tools available for this purpose, though the need of settings for each repository requires initial setup and browsing code (that was committed earlier by other people) may have style that other people consider as not-readable. Time/resources/trust can be a constraint I haven't thought of, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

It's true that the repository style settings require initial setup, BUT the same settings could be used by all developers (assuming they are all using the same reformatting tool).

Answer (score 1):

I  think that the issue that Caramiriel wants to bring up here, is the fact that, when doing a diff between two versions of a code-file in a SourceControl system, you get false positives because of changes in coding style.

The team of developers that work on the same project can share the same formatting settings but there will always be some friction, since everybody has his own coding style and has to make compromises with his fellow team members.
IMHO it would be a great feature to automatically apply a certain coding style at checkin (configured on server level), and apply your own coding style when you perform a get.
Problem here offcourse, is that the reformat when getting the file, will cause a checkout ...

Comment: Diffing is one thing, merging is another. Maybe another style configuration is better for statement merging. Consider code sample 1 and 2. I think it's easier to merge statements for code sample 1. Current limitation is the software that manages repositories, if I read your post correctly. Thanks for the comment btw.